# xpages go to a previous principal xpage

Tags: xpages

My scenario:

There is a navigator, having some links which redirect the user to some `.xsp`. Those `.xsp` contains some views listing certain documents. The users can create new documents using:

```
<xp:this.action>
                <xp:openPage name="/doc.xsp" target="newDocument"></xp:openPage>
</xp:this.action>
```

Inside this doc., they can create other docs. ( with other datasource declared ) inside a `<xe:dialog>`. It has only one `save and close` button, which redirects me: into the current doc. if I opened the dialog from there or it directs me to the `.xsp` described above.

The problem: if I create a new Doc. and from its inside I create some docs from the dialog, with my `Save` button, I must hit it 2 times ( in most cases ) to redirect me to those `.xsp` described above. Why? because in this case my desired destination .xsp is not the PreviousPage, but the PreviousPreviousPage, the PreviousPage being  doc.xsp?action=newDocument and the current page it is doc.xsp?documentId=E1141A490316FD88C2257D3400322723&action=openDocument, considering the fact that the doc. was already saved to open the dialog and from the save and close button I just redirect the users back to the main doc.

```
<xp:button value="Save" id="buttonSave" styleClass="lotusFormButton"
                    rendered="#{javascript:currentDocument.isEditable()}">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="partial" immediate="false" save="false"
                        id="eventHandler1">
                        <xp:this.action>
                            <xp:actionGroup>
                                    <xp:saveDocument var="Cdoc"></xp:saveDocument>
                                <xp:openPage name="$$PreviousPage"></xp:openPage>
                            </xp:actionGroup>
                        </xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this solution and for my case it seems to be the most useful.

[Return-to-last-view](http://xcellerant.net/2013/03/15/return-to-last-view)

You just log the page name in a scope variable ( when you're opening a view - in my case the principal Xpage which contains the view ) , and from the `Save` button I just return to the last view opened ( contained by the xpage ).

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got it right:

You may want to have a look at "navigation rules". Your save button e.g. could return a SSJS value:

```
return "home"
```

where 'home' is the name of your rule, directing you to your index.xsp.
So no matter what you did when you used your doc.xsp, how many dialogs you opened, if you click this button that uses the nav rule it will bring you to the page. You used the $$PreviousPage placeholder which simply generates a simple CSJS

```
history.go(-1)
```

which then will get you in the trouble you face now.

Comment: I've just found this suggestion http://xcellerant.net/2013/03/15/return-to-last-view/ . I will try to implement it. Also, I will try your suggestion, too, and let you know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the code for the Save button in the dialog with the following, assuming the id for the xe:dialog is dialog1:

```
 <xp:button value="Save" id="buttonSave" styleClass="lotusFormButton"
                rendered="#{javascript:currentDocument.isEditable()}">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                 Cdoc.save();
                 var c = getComponent("dialog1");
                 c.hide("refreshPanel1");
            }]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
 </xp:button>
```

The optional "refreshPanel1" passed to the hide method is the id of the containing element on the XPage to perform a partial refresh when the dialog is closed.